# cannot read input while calling from function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

below you will find a simple code.
i am calling function input if the read input is Y
however read command in input function never executes.

```
#!/bin/bash
input() {
    read -p "Press any key to continue..." # read input (this part never executed) 
}

mg() # prompt user for y=true, n=false
{
    [ $FORCE ] && echo>&2 "$* (forced)" && return
    while read<&2 -p "$* (Y/N)? [Y] " YN
    do
        [ -z "$YN" -o "$YN" = Y ] && return
        [ "$YN" = N ] && return 1
    done
    err "failed to read from YN   $*"    
}


if mg "Enter Input?"       
then in="yes" | input # call function input if mg return Y
else in="no"
fi
```

Comment: Try executing with "bash -x <your_script>" to see what's going on.

Comment: Any specific reason for using a pipe `|` in if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
then in="yes" | input
```

is the issue. You don't want to pipe the assignment of `in` into `input`. Separate the commands with a semicolon or a newline:

```
then in="yes"; input
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `input` is getting its standard output from the parameter assignment. As soon as the assignment completes, its (nonexistant) standard output is closed, which `read` interprets as EOF which causes the `read` to return.

Use a semi-colon instead.

```
if mg "Enter Input?"
then in="yes"; input
else in="no"
fi
```

(Removing the pipeline also allows `in` to be assigned in the current shell, not in the pipeline-induced subshell.)